React js not fetching and rendering after importing data
I fetch from db new data and render (setState) after importing excel data,    problem not working.    I have played around to trying to get it working so copied the fetch from getItems to simplifiedFunction. I had also problem when starting the rendering was in infinite loop, but then I added a parameter (value) to control when to fetch. In the code there is also a excel export, that works fine .I'm a beginner with React js
App.js
    simplifiedFunction (value) {
    let b = value
    //this.state.upd=b
    if (b==true)
    {
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/crud')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(items => this.setState({items}))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }
 

in render....
    <Excelfileinp 
    simplifiedFunction = {this.simplifiedFunction} 
    />

Excelfileinp.js
this call back to App.js

    this.props.simplifiedFunction(true)


code part
        fetch('http://localhost:3000/crudexcel', {
          method: 'post',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          }, 
          body: JSON.stringify(mdata1)        
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(item => {
          if(Array.isArray(item)) {
            this.props.simplifiedFunction(true)
          } else {
            console.log('failure')
          }
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
        
      };

App.js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Container, Row, Col } from 'reactstrap'
import ModalForm from './Components/Modals/Modal'
import DataTable from './Components/Tables/DataTable'
import ReactExport from "react-export-excel";
import FileInput from './FileInput';
import Excelfileinp from './Excelfileinp';

const ExcelFile = ReactExport.ExcelFile;
const ExcelSheet = ReactExport.ExcelFile.ExcelSheet;
const ExcelColumn = ReactExport.ExcelFile.ExcelColumn;


class App extends Component {
  state = {
    items: []
  }

  
  getItems(value){
    if (value === true)
      {
      fetch('http://localhost:3000/crud')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(items => this.setState({items}))
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
      }
  }


  addItemToState = (item) => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      items: [...prevState.items, item]
    }))
  }

  updateState = (item) => {
    const itemIndex = this.state.items.findIndex(data => data.id === item.id)
    const newArray = [
    // destructure all items from beginning to the indexed item
      ...this.state.items.slice(0, itemIndex),
    // add the updated item to the array
      item,
    // add the rest of the items to the array from the index after the replaced item
      ...this.state.items.slice(itemIndex + 1)
    ]
    this.setState({ items: newArray })
  }

  deleteItemFromState = (id) => {
    const updatedItems = this.state.items.filter(item => item.id !== id)
    this.setState({ items: updatedItems })
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    //this.state.upd=true
    this.getItems(true)
    //this.state.upd=false
  }
  simplifiedFunction (value) {
    let b = value
    //this.state.upd=b
    if (b==true)
    {
    //this.getItems(true)
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/crud')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(items => this.setState({items}))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }
    //this.state.upd=false
  
  }

  
  render() {
    return (
      <Container className="App">
        <Row>
          <Col>
            <h1 style={{margin: "20px 0"}}>CRUD Database</h1>
          </Col>
        </Row>
        <Row>
          <Col>
            <DataTable items={this.state.items} updateState={this.updateState} deleteItemFromState={this.deleteItemFromState} />
          </Col>          
        </Row>
        <Row>
          <Col>
            <ModalForm buttonLabel="Add Item" addItemToState={this.addItemToState}/>
            <div>
            <Excelfileinp 
            simplifiedFunction = {this.simplifiedFunction} 
            />
            </div>
          </Col>
        </Row>
        <ExcelFile element={<button>Download Data</button>}>
            <ExcelSheet data={this.state.items} name="items">
                <ExcelColumn label="id" value="id"/>
                <ExcelColumn label="first" value="first"/>
                <ExcelColumn label="last" value="last"/>
                <ExcelColumn label="email" value="email"/>
                <ExcelColumn label="phone" value="phone"/>
                <ExcelColumn label="location" value="location"/>
                <ExcelColumn label="hobby" value="hobby"/>
            </ExcelSheet>
        </ExcelFile>
      </Container> 
  )
  }  
}

export default App


Excelfileinp.js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';

function renderData(passData) {
    let json = [];

    for(let i = 1; i < passData.length; i++) {
      //if (i==1)
      //{
      let body = {};
      body['id'] = passData[i][0];
      body['first'] = passData[i][1];
      body['last'] = passData[i][2];
      body['email'] = passData[i][3];
      body['phone'] = passData[i][4];
      body['location'] = passData[i][5];
      body['hobby'] = passData[i][6];

      json.push(body);
    //}
  }
  return json;
}  

class Excelfileinp extends React.Component {
    
    constructor( props ) {
      super( props );
  
      this.inputFileRef = React.createRef();
      this.onFileChange = this.handleFileChange.bind( this );
      this.onBtnClick = this.handleBtnClick.bind( this );
    }

  
    handleFileChange( e ) {
      /*Selected files data can be collected here.*/
      //console.log( e.target.files );
      const file = e.target.files[0];
      const reader = new FileReader();
  
      reader.onload = (event) => {
        const data = new Uint8Array(event.target.result);
        const workbook = XLSX.read(data, { type: 'array' });
        const sheetName = workbook.SheetNames[0];
        const sheet = workbook.Sheets[sheetName];
        const jsonData = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(sheet, { header: 1 });
  
        const mdata0 = renderData(jsonData);
        const mdata = JSON.stringify(mdata0);
        const mdata1 = JSON.parse(mdata);
        
        fetch('http://localhost:3000/crudexcel', {
          method: 'post',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          }, 
          body: JSON.stringify(mdata1)        
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(item => {
          if(Array.isArray(item)) {
            //this.props.setupd=true
            this.props.simplifiedFunction(true)
            //this.props.setupd=false
            //variable.props.toggle()
          } else {
            console.log('failure')
          }
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
        
      };
  
      reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);

    }
  
    handleBtnClick() {
      /*Collecting node-element and performing click*/
      this.inputFileRef.current.click();
    }
  
    render() {
      return (
          <input
            type="file"
            ref={this.inputFileRef}
            onChange={this.onFileChange}
          />
      )
    }
  } export default Excelfileinp;

debug done.. coming to App.js but fetch do nothing. get no error


Your problem is most likely coming from here:
<Excelfileinp simplifiedFunction = {this.simplifiedFunction} />

The keyword this can be really annoying in JavaScript. When you call a function in JS, this inside the function refers to whatever was to the left of the dot when you called the function.
Take this class for example
class Dog {
    say(word) {
        console.log(word);
    }

    bark() {
        this.say('Woof');
    }
}

If you have an instance let dog = new Dog(); and you call dog.bark();, this inside the function is bound to the dog. But if you do it like let f = dog.bark; f();, it is no longer bound to that dog, so this.say('Woof') will not work.
There are a few ways to fix this.
The easiest is to actually call the function inside a lambda:
<Excelfileinp simplifiedFunction = {() => this.simplifiedFunction()} />

Another is to make it an arrow function, which will make sure that this is always bound to the class.
simplifiedFunction: (value) => {
...
}


Thank you, I will learn more about scope and js it's coding basics. I put this <Excelfileinp simplifiedFunction = {() => this.simplifiedFunction()} /> in my code and it helped, I also do't need a if to control when to fetch data and fetching is working after new data is imported.
